# $z_0$ be a point of a domain of a complex valued function which is of isolated singularity.whether $z_0$ is a point of discontinuity of $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> Let $f : D  \to \mathbb C$ be a function and $z_0$ be a point of isolated singularity.
>   Where $D$ is a domain.

**My question is whether $z_0$ is a point of discontinuity of $f$ or not?**

If not necessarily then please give some example.I have  tried to find this question in stack exchange but failed.

Comment: @AkashYadav Okay,you are right.In removable singularity we do not consider $z_0$ to be a point of domain.But what happens if it in our domain.?

Comment: If it's a singularity, how can it be in domain? How will you define f at a pole, say?

Comment: @AkashYadav please see Kavi Rama Murthy's answer.

Comment: I have seen the answer and the point is your question doesn't make sense. This is because we don't discuss continuity at points which are not in domain, unless you assign an arbitrary value at that point which makes no sense either.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)=\frac  1 z$ if $z\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$. Then $0$ is an isolated singularity but $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

If $f$ is continuous at $z_0$ then $f$ cannot have an isolated singularity at $z_0$. It is automatically analytic at $z_0$.

Comment: No my question is to show that at $z_0$ ,f is not necessary discontinuous or f is always discontinuous.

Comment: @LAMDA I have edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry,but can you please elaborate the 2nd part of your answer.I am a new learner of complex analysis.

Comment: Riemann's Theorem on removable singularities says that if $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ and if $f$ is bounded in some disk around $z_0$ then there exists a complex number $c$ such that the function $g(z)=f(z)$ for $z \neq z_0$, $g(z_0)=c$ is analytic (hence also continuous at $z_0$). It follows that $c=\lim_{z \to z_0} g(z)=\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)=f(z_0)$ so $g$ coincides with $f$. This means $f$ has no singularity at $z_0$.  @LAMDA